# Changing a root's file on external drive from another system

Tags: filesystems, mount, root

If I use one system to format an external drive (not an encrypted partition, just a standard filesystem) and then create a file owned by root and then mount that drive on another system, will I be able to change that file using the root account of the second system? Does the answer depend on the filesystem?

Maybe the answer to this question exists already on the internet, but I couldn't find it because my search queries were always too long... Sorry about that.

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems like a very straightforward experiment.

Comment: @JimL. Well it is, but not everyone has two systems... So I can't test it, sorry.

Comment: I would say that's a 99.9% Yes - I can't imagine what would cause the 0.1% possibility of failure, but I'll never say 100%, that way I can't be wrong :p

Comment: Linux default access control is very simple and does not link files to the computer where they are created. Access is controlled using owner's UID/GID and permission bits, that's all. Thus, the answer to your question is yes. I wonder if security frameworks like AppArmor or SELinux could be configured to change that behaviour though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as a root user, or superuser, you would be able to change that file in the second system.

But let's think of a different scenario. If you set owner-only access to a file in the first system, you would not be able to access the file in another system; unless you had the same user information as the first system. A system superuser (or root) would be able to access and change the permission bits of the restricted file.

File access restrictions across different systems are possible when programs embed system and user-related information into the file. This information is sometimes referred to as the status or metadata of the file, and it informs a system about the owner and permission configuration of a file.

Try viewing the status or metadata information for your file using the `stat` command:

```
# stat --terse filename.ext
```

Or to simply view the file's permission bits, user id, and username of the owner, try the command as

```
# stat -c 'PERMISSION: %a | USER ID OF OWNER: %u | USERNAME OF OWNER: %U' some-file.txt
PERMISSION: 644 | USER ID OF OWNER: 1003 | USERNAME OF OWNER: ukass
```

Here you can read more about stat (and similar commands): https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat